# Docker containers complain about missing files which exist in their filesystem

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

I recently moved my code repo from a One drive folder to my C: drive, trying to escape sync issues wiping files (that's another issue).

Before doing so both my dev and prod compose files worked as expected (under source control).

Moving the files across (cloning from the repo and checking out to the branch) I ran my dev compose file which worked again as expected however my prod started complaining about "no such file or directory", "not found". I decided to snapshot the filesystem and check and could see the files and could cat the contents. So why is docker complaining?

My compose file does not use any hardcoded file paths, all relative and its evident the files are being copied across.

Compose errors:

```
exec docker/deployment/folder/scripts/run.sh: no such file or directory
```

Snapshot:

```
/app$ cat docker/deployment/folder/scripts/run.sh
#!/bin/sh
```

As previously mentioned this worked running from a different local dir location. I can't imaging how that would make any difference.

Thanks in advance for any support.

Comment: Please update your question to include a `docker-compose.yaml` file (and possibly a `Dockerfile`, if you're using a custom image) that reproduces the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Found the issue, vs code had updated the end-of-line sequence to crlf instead of lf.